# Debian Squeeze and exim4: cannot send mail

Tags: debian, exim

Got this error after install and config of **exim4-daemon-light** and **mailutils** packages on Debian Squeeze. This package is aimed to send automatic messages from websites, like email confirmation and stuff.

Configuration after package install:

> dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config

You'll be presented with a welcome screen, followed by a screen asking what type mail delivery you'd like to support. Choose the option for "internet site" and select "Ok" to continue.

After many configuration sceens you can test mail with:

> echo "test message" | mail -s "test
>   message" user@domain.com

Here is the response:

```
root@server:/etc# echo "test message" | mail -s "test message" user@domain.com
2011-03-02 20:34:59 1PuxRT-0001Aj-T9 Cannot open main log file "/var/log/exim4/mainlog": Permission denied: euid=101 egid=103
2011-03-02 20:34:59 1PuxRT-0001Aj-T9 <= root@debian U=root P=local S=331
2011-03-02 20:34:59 1PuxRT-0001Aj-T9 Cannot open main log file "/var/log/exim4/mainlog": Permission denied: euid=101 egid=103 exim: could not open panic log - aborting: see message(s) above Can't send mail: sendmail process failed with error code 1
```

There is no **/var/log/exim4** directory on my server. I tried to create it, but it didn't work.

Please, can someone help me?

Best regards,
Fernando

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make sure that `/var/log/exim4` is owned an writable by Debian-exim:

```
chmod -R u+rw /var/log/exim4
chown -R Debian-exim /var/log/exim4
```

Answer (score 1):

try to 'touch' that file thats missing.

`mkdir -p /var/log/exim4`

`touch /var/log/exim4/mainlog`

Answer (score 0):

And don't forget to

```
sudo chown -R Debian-exim:adm /var/log/exim4
```

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an issue with the linode base deployment images:

http://forum.linode.com/viewtopic.php?p=37062&sid=112cbcbf147285968fa01607b42efe61

which they indicate they have now fixed (and which Fernando has probably seen by now, as the previous forum poster.)